# Developer Console - units used for duration?

Tags: developer-console

So I've run a successful test in the Dev Console. One of the columns visible on that tab is duration.  My result is "0:28".  I'm not sure if that is 28 seconds, .28 seconds or 28 milliseconds.  Any ideas?  BTW, the log shows the test starting at:

15:17:38:301

and ending at

15:18:01:201

which appears to be a total duration of just under 23 seconds for everything.  That suggests 28 seconds is not the answer, but I'd like to know what the units are for sure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes those are milliseconds. You can see them talking about this topic here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Troubleshooting_Apex_Performance_Problems
(Where there are 0.2 'duration' gaps which are milliseconds in between each case)

in your case that will be 280 milliseconds

Comment: Thanks!  That link has reminded me that I can also wrap key line(s) with system.debug() statements to get more specific.

Comment: You're welcome! Mark it as an answer if it helps so others can reference to this too :)

Comment: I usually wait a day or two before adding the check (encourages other answers), but I don't think there's much more to say on this one.